# Как анимировать бургер?

Tags: html, css, jquery

Пример: https://ubc-build.com.ua/en/our-team

```js
$('.mobile-wrap').on('click', function() {
  $('.line-burger').toggleClass('line-active');
  $('.main-header__row').toggleClass('main-header__row--active')
});
```

```css
.mobile-wrap {
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.line-burger {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 18px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s width;
}

.line-burger:after,
.line-burger:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 18px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.line-burger:after {
  top: calc(100% + 4px);
}

.line-burger:before {
  bottom: calc(100% + 4px);
}

.line-active {
  width: 0;
}

.line-active:after {
  top: 7px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.line-active:before {
  bottom: 7px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

.main-nav__toggle {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile-wrap">
  <div class="main-nav__toggle">
    <span class="line-burger"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```